# SGE: downtime planning

Tags: gridengine

I need to plan a downtime for a maintenance of my environment (or some part of my environment) by means of Sun Grid Engine. Is it possible to somehow use backfilling information to tell the grid engine to plan only those jobs on cluster which are able to finish (i have backfilling information) till let's say 10 am next day? Can I then at 10 am rely on the fact that all compute nodes are clean, jobs are only queued, no job is planned and so that I can start maintenance?

Thank you for your time.

mousee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to submit an advance reservation for the duration of your maintenance window. Jobs that are submitted with a runtime request that's guaranteed not to go in to the reservation window will continue to be scheduled. You need to be enforcing runtime requests in your cluster via the s_rt or h_rt resource requests and all jobs must have them, otherwise GridEngine will go ahead and schedule them anyway and they may run in to your maintenance window.

Comment: Thank you very much Kamil, I'll try and let you know about the result.